# Server configured to send 404 to requests from cURL?

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-404

I am doing some automation for a client and was planning on running some php scripts via cURL in the process.  However URLs that work fine in a browser are coming up 404 when hit by cURL.  I have seen mention elsewhere that some servers are configured to block cURL in this manner.

Is this a setting I could edit in `httpd.conf`?  Doesn't seem to be in `php.ini`.

My code is like so:

```
  $url = "http://site.com/xxx/curl.php?cID=$c->cID&db=$c->db&un=$c->un&/";
  echo "$url";

  // spoofing FireFox 2.0
  $useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) 
    Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";
  $ch = curl_init ($url) ;
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1) ;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
  $res = curl_exec ($ch);
```

When I echo `$res` I get the code from the default 404 error page.  If I copy the echoed $url and paste into browser I get the page fine.  Also tried using relative path and full server path.

The user agent spoofing was added today to try to see if saying I wasn't cURL would help but nothing in the response changed.

Any thoughts on how to track down the root cause of this or better yet solve it?

Comment: Dump the full set of headers output by firefox.  Dump the full set of headers currently output by curl.  Keep tweaking your curl settings until they match.

If your headers are identical (including cookies), and you're requesting pages at a realistic rate, there's no real way to tell the difference between curl and a real browser.

...Well, a real browser requests images and scripts -- not just HTML :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the kind folks at The Planet have some internal routing issues with this account.  Bad hostname settings in /etc/sysconfig/network and bad resolvers in /etc/resolv.conf among other things. This and a number of other sites were recently migrated from one of their servers to another.  Not fixed yet but that was why the 404.

Thanks.